# Perform form validation of nested form or nested form component in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I am using Angular 7 and Template Driven Forms. I have angular form in that form I'm calling another component (or Form) and there as well I have applied required and **template driven validations**.

Another form holds `Department Name` and which is `mandatory` while creating `Student`. When All the required fields have been populated then only I want to enable the **`save()`** button. But since department Name field is in different component, how will I check if that field is populated and now I should enable the button?

```
<div>
    <form novalidate #f=ngForm>
        <div style="position: relative;">
            <div class="awr-input">
                <label class="awr-inputbox-label">
                    Owner Name
                    <span class="awr-required">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">
                            *
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </label>
                <app-dept (selectedElement)=populateDepartment($event) [employeeName]=(student.studentName)></app-dept>
            </div>
        </div>
        .....
        .....
        .....
        <div class="fixed-bottom footer">
            <div class="awr-container">
                <div class="awr-row">
                    <div class="awr-col-12">
                        <div class="btn-group-2 float-right">
                            <div class="awr-cta float-right">
                                <div class="cta-with-icon">
                                    <button type="submit" class="awr-btn awr-btn-primary" title="Submit" aria-label="Save" (click)="saveStudent()" [disabled]="!f.form.valid">
                                        Save
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </form>
</div>
```

**dept.component.html**

```
<form novalidate #f1=ngForm>
    <div class="input-container">
        <input type="text" id="" class="input-box" aria-required="true" minlength="0" maxlength="100" autocomplete="off"
            width="0" min="" max="" step="" [(ngModel)]="inputField" name="inputField" (input)=getDept() required
            #deptName="ngModel">
    </div>

    <div class="input-flydown flydownStyle" *ngIf="deptList?.length > 0">
        <div>
            <dl *ngFor="let dept of deptList">
                <dt><a class="dxp-cta-link" (click)="sendDept(dept)">{{dept.name}}</a>
                </dt>
                <dd>{{dept.eId}} {{dept.jobTitle}}</dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="deptName.invalid && (deptName.dirty || deptName.touched)" class="dxp-error dxp-required">
            Dept Name is mandatory.
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having two different forms, just use nesting instead.

Read more **[here, written by the awesome guru Alexey Zuev](https://medium.com/@a.yurich.zuev/angular-nested-template-driven-form-4a3de2042475)**

So basically just provide in child component:

```ts
@Component({
  // ...
  viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm }]
})
```

and in child template just remove the form tags. The parent will know about this child form and when the form controls in child are valid.

**DEMO with stripped version of your code: [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ruvyhh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: Great! Glad to help :)

Comment: Could you please guide me here as well : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58092282/angular-7-how-to-read-service-side-validations-from-object-using-template-driv ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest form of accomplishing this is to use `ViewChild`. You can reference the component with a `templateRef` then check to see values of that member.

```js
@ViewChild('appDept') appDept: DepartmentComponent;

// do/check stuff with this.appDept
```

```html
<app-dept (selectedElement)=populateDepartment($event) [employeeName]=(student.studentName) #appDept></app-dept>
```

Comment: How will I checked the nested form is valid or not ? How to take decision to show save button?

Comment: Something like this, ‘this.appDept.formName.valid’. Your formName or another template ref depending on you have your form setup.

Comment: ‘this.appDept.deptName’ would be you’re reference. You just check it has a value

Comment: What would I need to use here in my example `[disabled]="!f.form.valid"` ?